# Proper implementation of relations

Tags: parse-platform, backendless

I'm trying to design a data model involving users who are in groups, and post to groups, and the posts have comments.

How do would I make this ready to be configured into the datatable? Am I using proper data types, and implementing relationships properly?
If not please give suggestions.

```
User Class
objectID [String]| userName [String]| password [String] | groupsUserBelongsTo [Array of numbers]| emailAddress [String]


Group Class
objectId [Int]| groupName [String] | UserIDsOfGroupMembers (one to many relation to userID.user)| PostsOfGroups (one to many relation to objectId.post)


Post Class 
objectId [String]| Timestamp [String] | postSubject [String]| postBody [String]| groupsPostBelongsTo [Array]| postAuthor [String] | commentsOfGroups (one to many relation to objectId.comment)

Comment Class 
objectId [String]| Timestamp [String] | commentBody[String]| postCommentsBelongsTo [Array] | commentAuthor [String]
```

I really feel like I could add more relations but I can't think of any, and I'm not using the right type of relation (many to many, one to one etc.).

Comment: Can a post be in many groups? Can a comment be on many posts? Why do you think more relations are better / required?

Comment: I've been told their better, and I don't really know any way not involving relations.